# Ubuntu 14.04 not downloading

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to download ubuntu 14.04 from the ubuntu site. Though my internet speed is fairly good, it becomes too small <14kb/sec when the ubuntu download starts and the download never completes.
I have downloaded ubuntu many times before too but sucha  problem never came.
What should I do?

Comment: Maybe the specific mirror it's pulling the image from is running slow? I suggest you try bittorrent for this if possible (and yes, it is completely legal to use bittorrent to download Ubuntu). You tend to get better speed that way, and it's much more forgiving of connection problems.

Comment: I have linux OS. Bittorent is for windows, mac and android. I there a way to use it on linux platform too.

Answer (score 1):

Use a torrent client instead of downloading the iso image directly, install [Utorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/) if you're downloading from within Windows, or [Transmission](https://www.transmissionbt.com/) if you are downloading from within Linux, and download the torrent file from [official Ubuntu download page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/), load torrent file in utorrent/Transmission, and the iso image should be present on your desktop in just a few minutes.

By the way, I suggest that you scroll down on the download page and choose Ubuntu 14.04.1 version instead of Ubuntu 14.04. The links for torrent downloads are marked with `.torrent` at the end.

If Ubuntu download page is the only page where you are experiencing download speed limitation, and you can download at high speed from other pages check with your Internet provider, and ask why this happens. If you have the same problem when downloading other software then there must be something wrong with your Internet connection, either some firewall related issues or some serious conflicts generated when using both IPv4 and IPv6 protocols at once.